# FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot delete cluster 'cdap-fusionpip-462363d2-a154-11e9-869a-16df235ccdf8' while it has other pending delete operations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

When deploying a Data Fusion pipeline, it keeps failing and throwing the following error,

> com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException:
>   io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot delete
>   cluster 'cdap-fusionpip-462363d2-a154-11e9-869a-16df235ccdf8' while it
>   has other pending delete operations.  at
>   com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:59)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:95)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123)
>   ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900)
>   ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811)
>   ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675)
>   ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]   at
>   io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:392)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:475)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:478)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:590)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212] Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
>   FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot delete cluster
>   'cdap-fusionpip-462363d2-a154-11e9-869a-16df235ccdf8' while it has
>   other pending delete operations.  at
>   io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526) ~[na:na]   ... 19
>   common frames omitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027286/while-running-data-fusion-pipeline-to-load-csv-file-from-gcs-to-bigquery-facing

Comment: I have resolved this issue. It was an ingress firewall rule blocking the communication between instances of the dataproc cluster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While running Data fusion pipeline to load csv file from GCS to BigQuery facing some issue regarding data-proc deprovisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027286/while-running-data-fusion-pipeline-to-load-csv-file-from-gcs-to-bigquery-facing)